# Can’t get a specific output using a boolean

Tags: c#, boolean

I want a specific output depending on wether the Boolean is set to true or not. I can’t seem to find the solution so I’m just asking here. I don’t what to output „true“ or „false“ but a specific text.

What I tried:

```
public class Program
{
    bool isAlive = true;
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (isAlive == true){
            Console.WriteLine("Is True");
        }
    }
}
```

What worked:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool isAlive = true;
        if (isAlive == true){
            Console.WriteLine("Is True");
        }
    }
}

The Error was that I tried to use the non-static variable in the static void. Thanks to everyone that helped.
```

Comment: `(mybool ? "Text for true" : "Text for false")`?

Comment: without any code it's pretty hard to help you. What "boolean" and what "output"?

Comment: Is this question about unity3d ?

Comment: Looks like you have a VS project there. You can't use Program.Main in Unity. If you are using Unity, more problems ahead.

Comment: I really hope you do not really have this code in `Unity` (which you added a tag for) ... Unity already is the main process framework and for sure you do not want another main method within it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do either

```
string output = bool_variable ? "true value" : "false value";
Debug.Log(output);
```

or

```
if(bool_variable == true){
    Debug.Log("true value")
}else{
    Debug.Log("false value")
}
```

---

## Edit:

You are getting the non-static error because you are trying to access `isAlive` from a static method when it is not static. So you either need to create an instance of Program, make `isAlive` static, or remove the static keyword from `Main`.

Further more this does not seem to be a unity question since you are using Console.WriteLine and not implementing `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Thank you, I just had to put the boolean in the public static void, now everything works fine. And yes I am not using any Unity code since Im not at home and just wanted to test out code I want to implement later on.

Comment: @XEMIIX putting it in the function will work but it won't be visible to other methods, although the methods won't be static in unity. since i assume that method is static to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

{boolean_variable} ? "Boolean value is true" : "Boolean value is false"

Comment: „main.cs(8,12): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `?'
main.cs(8,38): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `:'“

Comment: this is pretty unlikely to help anyone, as the question utself is completely unclear. In particular we have no clue on what OP means by "output". Do you?

Comment: @XEMIIX Please add all relevant information into the **question**, not into **comments**.

Comment: this is wrong syntax the {} should not be there